# Go generics: infer type parameter for variadic function with zero arguments

Tags: go, generics, variadic-functions

Let's say I have a function with two generic parameters, one of them variadic:

```golang
func Constructor[F any, Opt any](f F, opts ...Opt) {}
```

Calling this function works fine if I pass in a few options:

```golang
Constructor(func() *myService { return ... }, 1, 2, 3)
```

However, calling it without any `Opt`s fails:

```golang
Construtor(func() *myService { return ... })
```

The compiler complains:

> Cannot use 'func() *myService' (type func() *myService) as the type (F, Opt) or F

I assume that’s because the compiler can’t figure out the type of `Opt` in this case.

While this makes sense, it’s annoying nevertheless. The compiler doesn't *need* the type of `Opt`, since it's empty.

One way to work around this is to define two functions, `Constructor` and `ConstructorWithOpts`. It would be really nice to just have a single function though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> The compiler doesn't need the type of Opt, since it's empty.

Even if the *caller* decides to supply zero arguments, the body of the function can still operate with the value of the variadic parameter. So the compiler definitely needs the type of `Opt`.

Furthermore the rules for [type inference](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_inference) are clear:

> Type inference is based on
>
> - a type parameter list
> - a substitution map M initialized with the known
>   type arguments, if any
> - a (possibly empty) list of ordinary function
>   arguments (in case of a function call only)

When you have zero arguments for a certain type parameter, the third option as of above isn't applicable. If `F` and `Opt` are completely unrelated, the second option is also not applicable.

As a corollary, consider that the caller must supply all the type args if they ever need to declare a **value** of your `Constructor` function type:

```
ctor := Constructor[func(), any] // not called!
ctor(f, 1, 2, 3)
```

The cleanest is obviously to let the compiler infer `F` and specify `Opts` explicitly, although this requires inverting the order of the type parameters in the function declaration, so that clients can supply the first and omit the second. You may define an `any` type to improve readability:

```
func Constructor[Opt any, F any](f F, opts ...Opt) {}

type NoOpts any // just for better readability

func main() {
    f := func() *myService { return ... }

    // NoOpts instantiates Opt; F inferred
    Constructor[NoOpts](f)
}
```

Otherwise just make `Constructor` non-variadic:

```
func Constructor[F any](f F) {
    ConstructorWithOpts[F, any](f)
}

func ConstructorWithOpts[F any, Opt any](f F, opts ...Opt) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may provide an empty slice for the variadic argument:

```
Constructor(func() *myService { return nil }, []int{}...)
```

You can also pass `nil`, but it's more verbose:

```
Constructor(func() *myService { return nil }, ([]int)(nil)...)
```

Or provide values for the type parameters:

```
Constructor[func() *myService, any](func() *myService { return nil })
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qxb8y2uh7Rd).

Comment: These work, but they require the user of the API to do highly non-obvious changes. I'd like to avoid that.